# How to wait for command line input in Go

Tags: go

I want to display a "> ", and then have the program wait for the user to type something into the command line and hit enter (and ultimately store that as a byte slice). In Java I would have done something like:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("> ");
String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
```

I've tried some things involving `os.Args, console.ReadBytes('\n')`, and `bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)`, but I still haven't figured it out. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some Go code would have probably been helpful so I could tell you what you did wrong. But here is how you would do this in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    buf := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("> ")
    sentence, err := buf.ReadBytes('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(string(sentence))
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want a string then use buf.ReadString('\n') as well.

Comment: The inputting code could then be put in a loop, sending its lines of text along a channel to the consuming goroutine. This addition provides a naturally-concurrent way of expressing the handling of user input.